# python modify mutable iterator

Tags: python, iterator, generator

The code is like following:

```
f=open('test.txt')
file=iter(f)
```

When I do

```
next(file)
```

It will print line by line of file.
But when I modified the test.txt file and saved it, the next(file) still printed the original file content.

Does iterator store the complete file in the memory?
If not why the content of the file didn't get updated?

Comment: No, a file iterator doesn’t store the file content in memory. It stores the position in the file. The file is usually loaded by chunks so it stores a buffer (by default 8192 bytes but it can vary).

Comment: btw, `f` object itself is an iterator with `f.next` method (and `f.__next__` in Python 3.+) ..you do not need to pass it `iter(...)` function explicitly

Comment: So If my file size is bigger than 8192 bytes buffer size then theoretically if I modified the last line of file, the result will be the new content not the original content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, as an iterator the `file` object stores only a look-ahead buffer, not the complete file, in memory. This makes it efficient for large files.

Since there is this look-ahead buffer, changes made to the file won't be reflected to the `next` method. However, you can use the `seek` method to clear this buffer so the next call to the `next` method will return the updated content:

```
f.seek(f.tell()) # seek the current position only to clear the look-ahead buffer
print(next(f)) # prints the updated next line from the current position
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I aware as well. But if that is the case, why modify the physical file content is not affecting the next line ?

Comment: I've updated my answer with an explanation and a solution.

Comment: So If my file size is bigger than 8192 bytes buffer size then theoretically if I modified the last line of file, the result will be the new content not the original content?

Comment: Yes that would be the case.

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose [open()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) reads 2 letters at a time. (Actual value is [io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE))

```
f=open('test.txt')
```

You've created a file object, `_io.TextIOWrapper` which, oversimplified, is like `[{read from 0 to io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE of test.txt}, ...}`

```
file=iter(f)
```

You've created a iterator of `_io.TextIOWrapper` with data like this: `[{read from 0 to 1}, ... {read from n-1 to n}]`

```
next(file)
```

[next()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) has went through the first item of `file`, read it, and printed it.

## Let's learn from an example.

### Reading normally

*test.txt*

```
what a beautiful day
```

We will open the file, iter(), and list() to open and iter through all of it and make a list.

```
In [1]: f = open('test.txt')

In [2]: list(iter(f))
Out[2]: ['what a beautiful day']
```

Just as expected.

### File changes after `open()`

```
In [1]: f = open('test.txt')
```

We've opened the file.

We will now append `hello open()` to test.txt.

*test.txt*

```
what a beautiful day

hello open()
```

and then iter() and list() it.

```
In [2]: list(iter(f))
Out[2]: ['what a beautiful day\n', '\n', 'hello open()']
```

The changed contents are seen. We can see that `open()` does not actually read the file.

### File changes after `iter()`

```
In [1]: f = open('test.txt')

In [2]: i = iter(f)
```

We've opened the file and `iter()`d.

We will now append `hello iter()`

*test.txt*

```
what a beautiful day

hello open()

hello iter()
```

and then  list() it.

```
In [3]: list(i)
Out[3]: ['what a beautiful day\n', '\n', 'hello open()\n', '\n', 'hello iter()']
```

The changed contents are seen. We can also see that `iter()` does not actually read the file.